# Is there a way to use the Google Sheets API with Swift to build macOS Cocoa apps?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/ios?ver=swift) guide but when I execute `pod install` I get this error:

`` The platform of the target `ProjectName` (macOS 10.14) is not compatible with `GoogleSignIn (4.1.2)`, which does not support `osx`. ``

Do you know if there's a library out there which supports macOS apps too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pod is not supported x86. For mac you should go with GTMAppAuth.

Link: https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth